# How to set background into Android Gridview?

Tags: android, image, android-layout, gridview, background

i need to set image as background in android gridview. I have code which is using image view to load images. Following codes are my codes, please help me out to solve this issue.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if(!isNetworkAvailbale()){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internet Connection not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gridview);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Log.d("taust","sds");
            Toast.makeText(NuesHoundRSSActivity.this, "Item co" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

ImageAdapter

```
package com.nues.rss;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

   // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
   // imageView.setTag(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

// references to our images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
};


}
```

Any body knows how to set images as background of grid items ?

Comment: and what's the problem exactly?

Comment: Dude my issue is, i need to set images in mThumbIds array images as background in grid tiles, not as image view, because i need to put some content in to grid tiles. do you know how to do it ?

Comment: Have u tryed to set it in the `gridview.xml` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah yeah I get it. You want to show a Custom GridView with a Background set to each Grid Element and have some content over it.

First step is to create a layout and inflate it in the getView method of your Custom Adapter.

Here is a example,

http://www.technotalkative.com/android-gridview-example/

http://android-vogue.blogspot.in/2011/06/custom-gridview-in-android-with.html.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if you want to set a background image for the GridView (a background for the whole View, I mean), you just need to set that in your Activity class:

```
GridView gridview = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
gridview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sampleImage);
```

Or inside your XML layout file:

```
android:background="@drawable/sampleImage"
```

If, instead, you want to set a background image for all the items/elements of your GridView (the same image for all the items), you just need to do that in you ImageAdapter:

```
private Integer mThumbIds = R.drawable.sampleImage;
...
imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds);
```

Note that, inside your Adapter, you can even use a TextView instead of the ImageView, so that you can have images and texts together:

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView newView;
    if ( view == null ) {
        newView = new TextView( this.mContext );
    } else {
        newView = (TextView) view;
    }

    //Set the text:
    newView.setText( "TEXT" );  // android:text
    newView.setTextColor( Color.WHITE );  // android:textColor
    newView.setTextSize(25);  // android:textSize
    newView.setTypeface( Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD );  // android:textStyle
    newView.setGravity( Gravity.CENTER );  // android:gravity

    //Set backgorund image:
    newView.setBackgroundResource( this.thumbIds );  // android:background
    newView.setWidth(64);
    newView.setHeight(64);

    return newView;
}
```